# How does SOR increase the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

To solve a linear system $Ax=b$ using the [Gauss-Seidel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) method, the matrix $A$ can be decomposed as $A = L + D + U$ and solved iteratively using

$$ x^{(\text{new})} = -(D + L)^{-1} U x^{(\text{old})} + (D + L)^{-1} b $$

[Successive over-relaxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation) (SOR) adds a relaxation parameter $\omega \in [0,1]$ and solves the system using

$$ x^{(\omega)} = (1-\omega) x^{(\text{old})} + \omega x^{(\text{new})} $$

I saw a lecture that stated:

> The relaxation parameter acts like an effective increase in the eigenvalues of the matrix. A small enough value can enable convergence.

Can someone explain that statement to me? How does the relaxation parameter increase the eigenvalues and how does it affect convergence?

Comment: Is such lecture online?

Comment: I don't understand what $ x^{(\omega)} $ denotes.  How can the superscript be, say, $\frac12$?